# Why should we use the line voltage instead of phase voltage when we are calculate the charging current?

Tags: current, cables, charging

Why should we use the line voltage instead of phase voltage when we are calculate the charging current? I mean:

Charging current \$I_C=2\pi f C V=2\pi f C \frac{V_L}{\sqrt{3}}\times 10^{-6}\ \text {A/km} \$. (\$C\$ is Electrostatic capacity \$\mu F/km\$.\$f\$ means Hz,and \$V_L\$ means line voltage  )

Why don't we say \$I_C=2\pi f C \frac{V_P}{\sqrt{3}}\times 10^{-6}\ \text {A/km} \$  or \$I_C=2\pi f C \sqrt{3}V_P\times 10^{-6}\ \text {A/km}\$ ? \$V_P\$ means phase voltage

Comment: You forgot to mention how the capacitor (C?) connects to the three phase circuit. Also what is the \$10^{-6}\$ bit all about and why did it suddenly creep-in half way along your first formula line?

Comment: @Andyaka  what is the 10−6 bit all about and why did it suddenly creep-in half way along your first formula line THIS IS ALSO MY QUESTION!!But now i know the reason why,it just means \$\mu\$

Comment: That’s not an explanation of what your question is about.